# Is there any C++ code that can't be passed through an identity preprocessor macro?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, metaprogramming

Given:

```cpp
#define IDENTITY(...) __VA_ARGS__
```

Is there any code that the compiler will reject, that it would normally accept, when wrapped in an invocation of this macro? The simpler `#define IDENTITY(x) x` will fail if there are any commas but the above seems pretty robust, GCC happily accepts this:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

#define IDENTITY(...) __VA_ARGS__

IDENTITY(
    struct does_this_work {
        float yes;
        double appears_to;
    };

    template<class T> int what_about_this() {
        int x = 50, y = 0; // see the comma!
        for(int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
            printf("Hello world!");
        }
        return 3;
    }
)
```

Comment: Iʼm not sure but Iʼd experiment with code that has *other* macros in it.

Comment: What is the actual purpose of this macro ? What is the problem is solves ?

Comment: Why has the tag [tag:c] been picked for not a C code?

Comment: If you want to conditionally exclude code, you're better off using the standard preprocecessor convention, e.g. `#if FLAG` ... `#endif`.

Comment: I was interpreting this as more of a theoretical question than a practical one.  If it is for a practical purpose then yeah itʼd help to know what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#define IDENTITY(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define CAT(X,Y) X##Y

IDENTITY(CAT) IDENTITY((1,2))  // => CAT (1,2)

CAT (1,2) // => 12
```

Comment: I knew it could be broken with other macros.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, confusing the preprocessor, or using the preprocessor to confuse later phases of compilation, is always a viable strategy for breaking "robust" macros.

I have MingW32 (with gcc 10.3.0).  The following code compiles without error

```
#define FOO
FOO
#undef FOO
#define FOO2 int x();
FOO2;
```

but

```
#define IDENTITY(...) __VA_ARGS__

IDENTITY(
#define FOO
FOO
#undef FOO
#define FOO2 int x()
FOO2;
)
```

gets the compiler complaining bitterly (with command line `g++ -c test.cpp`).

```
test.cpp:7:5: error: 'FOO' does not name a type; did you mean 'FOO2'?
    7 |     FOO
      |     ^~~
test.cpp:1:23: note: in definition of macro 'IDENTITY'
    1 | #define IDENTITY(...) __VA_ARGS__
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

I haven't tried to pick apart why this happens.

[I estimate a non-zero likelihood that the question will now change to require no use of the processor in the argument of the macro].

Comment: lol, I will not change it but I am still curious if it's possible to do without using the preprocessor in the argument